# Automatic slide transition for only one slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've made some complex slide animations and transitions, but unless the slideshow is set to automatically transition, there will always be an awkward pause between slides. The idea is that I animated the elements of the slide to fancily disperse before moving on to the next slide, but you'd have to click once to animate them out, at which point the screen is blank, and you have to click again to bring on the next slide.

TL;DR: Is it possible to make only certain slides transition automatically, while still making some require click-through?

Comment: Hi Ben, As this is more of a technical support question, you're probably more likely to get answers on [su].

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible with PowerPoint 2010 (probably also with other versions, but I only have 2010).

If I understood you correctly you want this

1. one or more "normal" slides without animation
2. A slide that contains animation. (I will call it `animation slide`)
3. The next slide that should appear as soon as the animations of the `animation slide` have finished.
4. maybe more slides that should behave normally (i.e., appear on click)

Within the `animation slide` I assume you have content that should appear on click ... and then there is the "final content". This "final content" is the content that appears/starts to animate on click and after the animation is finished the next slide should appear.

**Solution**

1. Make a duplicate of the `animation slide`. Now you have two slides, lets call them S1 and S2.
2. Remove the final content from S1 (or the animation of the final content)
3. Make the content of S2 be in such a way that it only contains the final content/animation.
4. Set the first item of the animation to start "with previous"
5. Now select S2 and go to the "Transitions" ribbon. There you select the "cut" transition.
6. On the right side of the transition ribbon there is the "advance slide" area. Here you uncheck "on mouse click" and check "After:"
7. Set the time of the "After" setting to the same duration as your final animation
8. done

What will happen is: as soon as you advance your presentation to S2 the animation will start instantly and so will the transition timer. The moment the animation is done, the slide transition kicks in, and voilà: the next slide without a click.

Answer (score 1):

masgo's solution should work, but you may not need a duplicate of the animated slide.  Instead try this on the animated slide itself:

On the Transitions tab | Timing | Advance Slide put a check next to "Advance Slide ... After:" and leave it set at 0

Leave "On mouse click" checked if you wish.

This takes advantage of a feature | bug | quirk of PowerPoint:  that it won't transition to the next slide until all animations have finished playing.

Comment: Your solution doesnt work on MS Powerpoint 2016. Slide advance after last transition finished.

Comment: Do you mean after last animation finishes, rather than last transition?